# couldn't understand kern.osversion `16.7.0'

Tags: c, gcc, gtk, macos-sierra

I am current trying to compile this simple code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

GtkWidget *window;
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_widget_show(window);
g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
  G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  
gtk_main();
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to run this command:

```
gcc -o simple simple.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

But I receiving this EM:

```
couldn't understand kern.osversion `16.7.0'
```

My system macOS version is 10.12.6

Comment: Your compiler needs updating. It was built for an older version of macOS. That said, I don’t normally see that message with GNU’s `GCC` but I sometimes get it with other software such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess I found out what the issue was. The gcc version I was using was old although I installed a newer version through brew. So what I did is to edit the Path variable like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```